# Handling hidden field in multiple forms in Mvc 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, logic

I am having multiple forms in one page  and that page inherits one single model.Every form submission requires a common value. So, common value is stored in hidden field. The hidden field is kept global i.e outside of all the forms but my problem is whenever I submit form, that hidden field is coming to be empty.The hidden field is `@Html.HiddenfieldFor(m=>m.FkId)` and this FkId is of string type proprty in model i.e `public string FkId{get;set;}` .Can somebody please guide me how to handle this situation. If I keep hidden field in one of the forms then , it is coming in controller but only for that form submission where I have kept it. But I want that property to be set once and can use in all the form submissions.Please help me. How can I sort out this problem

Some related code

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab1"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
            <input type="Submit" id="btnTab1" value="Submit" onclick="CheckUser();"/>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab2"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
            <input type="Submit" id="btnTab2" value="Submit" />
        }
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Evaluation","SaveTab3"{new AjaxOptions { Onsucess= "DisplayMessage" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFieldfor(m=>m.fkID)
            <input type="Submit" id="btnTab3" value="Submit" />
        }
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayMessage(Json)
    {
       alert( $("#fkID").val(Json.hdn));
       // and Alert is showing the value
       $("#fkID").val(Json.hdn);
    }
</script>
```

In the Controller I have:

```
public ActionResult SaveTab1(Model obj)
{
    tbl ob =new tbl();
    ob.FkId=Obj.fkID;
    // after saving, I return

    return json(new{hdn=Obj.fkID})
}

public ActionResult SaveTab2(Model obj)
{
    tbl ob =new tbl();
    ob.FkId=Obj.fkID;

    //after saving, I return
    return json(new{hdn=Obj.fkID})
}
```

Similar for tab three, but unfortunately the hidden filed only comes for first form submit. Then I return value to view by json and again set the hidden field property but then it comes null for second form.Please help

Comment: What's `Html.HiddenFieldFor`? How come you don't even get a syntax error message? It should be `Html.HiddenFor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Instead of taking same field in all the forms which was not working, I have taken a unique and different Hidden field properties and after on seperated success function of each form and set the every hidden field a value in success method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your View does not inherit the Model, it is strongly-typed to the type of your Model. These two are completely different.

But, to answer your question, there's no such a thing as a global hidden field. Fields are not variables. If you want a field to be posted to your Controller, you need to put it inside the form. If you have multiple forms in your View, then you'll have to put the same hidden field inside all the those forms. So, you need to put `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FkId)` inside all the forms in your View.

UPDATE: By the way, it's not `Html.HiddenFieldFor`, it's `Html.HiddenFor`.

Comment: But if I do this , still that hidden Field is coming to be empty in Controller. It just shows value in case of first form submit not for others. I thought , if Once the form submits that it returns empty model, So, In controller when I get that property, I resend it back to view by this return Json(new{hdn=model.FkId}) and I again set the hidden field  at success event of ajax.begin form like this: function success(Json){$("#FkId").val(Json.Hdn)}. Now, as you have suggested , the hidden field should again store this value but it is showing null for second form submit. Please help me Sir.

Comment: Please update your question with the code for your Controller Action and your View.

Comment: Sir, I have updated the code.Please check and please help me.

Comment: What's `Html.HiddenFieldFor`? How come you don't even get a syntax error message? It should be `Html.HiddenFor`.

Comment: That is written here by mistake otherwise everything is fine syntactly. Please help me in building logic. syntax is not concerned.Thank you.